# How to use "has_object_permission" to check post request before saving to database?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can I use a condition like this to validate data before it is written to the database? I am using django rest framework

```
class WarehouseIsMemberOfCompany(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return True
        return False
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.user.company.id == obj.warehouse.company.id:
            return True
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as a permission class like the following.

When using the function-based APIView, you can set it in the decorator.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([WarehouseIsMemberOfCompany])
def function_name(request):
    ...
```

When using the class-based APIView, you can define the `permission_classes` attribute that contains your permission class.

```
class YourClassView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (WarehouseIsMemberOfCompany, )
    serializer_class = YourSerializer
```

Comment: I'm using class based views and apparently I'm doing something wrong as permissions don't work for post requests
I solved the problem through validators. But thanks anyway